# Disparar um evento usando JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, html, orientação-a-objetos

Gostaria de saber como se despacha um evento usando JavaScript.
Tentei usando o seguinte código:

```
var atual = document.getElementById('teste');
atual.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ alert('HUE HUE HUE BR') });
atual.dispatchEvent('mouseover');
```

mas aí acontece um erro falando que o evento não existe:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mx92ase/).

Comment: Recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação do método [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent), o parâmetro dele é um objeto `Event` não o nome do evento. Um exemplo seria: `dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'))`;

Comment: Valew cara! Descobri e na verdade eu tinha que criar o evento, ficou assim:
`var atual = document.getElementById('teste');

atual.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ alert('HUE HUE HUE BR') });
atual.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um trigger para um evento SEM jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243882/como-fazer-um-trigger-para-um-evento-sem-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo o conselho do colega Wakim, verifiquei na documentação e descobri que o evento não se cria sozinho, ou seja é necessario antes de dispara-lo cria-lo, ficou assim:

```
var atual = document.getElementById('teste');
atual.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ alert('HUE HUE HUE BR') });
atual.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));
```

Flw

Answer (score 1):

Precisei de algo parecido, mas para o mousewheel à uns tempos e fiz este código:

```
function createFakeMouseEvent(event, elemento) {

    var evt;
    if (!(window.mozInnerScreenX == null)) {
        // Firefox
        evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent(event, true, true, window, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
        elemento.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else {

        if ('onwheel' in document) {
            // Chrome, PhantomJS, Safari
            evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            evt.initMouseEvent(event, 0, 100, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, null, null, null);
            elemento.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else if ( !! document.createEvent) {
            // IE9
            evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            evt.initEvent(event, true, false);
            elemento.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else if (document.documentMode == 9) {
            // IE10+, Safari
            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            evt.initEvent(event, true, true);
            elemento.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else {
            // IE8
            var evt = document.createEventObject();
            elemento.fireEvent(event, evt);
        }
    }
}
```

O código ficou meio complexo porque browsers diferentes têm maneiras diferentes de disparar eventos... Mas deve funcionar para o que quer.

#### Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/vmvbb3hf/

Comment: Valew cara com certeza no futuro pode ser util mas como o projeto e IE9+ o dispacht normal vai servir.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa que pode ser mais simples é fazer uma arquitetura em camadas, o que permite chamar seu código diretamente sem ser por intermédio do sistema de eventos.

```
function huehue(){
    alert('HUE HUE HUE BR')
}

// Agora o evento só delega para uma função pronta
var atual = document.getElementById('teste');
atual.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ huehue() });

// E como huehue passou a ser uma função normal podemos chamá-la diretamente:
huehue();
```

Comment: Então Hugo o problema é normalmente quando vinculo uma função a um listener quero ter acesso ao target(this) por isso essa solução não é utilizada, Mas em um outro caso pode ser uma opção.
Valew.

Comment: Ve pode fazer huehue receber o nó como parâmetro:  No event listener vc faz `huehue(this)` e na chamada do lado de fora vc faz `huehue(atual)`