# Como fazer um trigger para um evento SEM jQuery?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

No jQuery, quando quero fazer um trigger para um evento existente, eu faço assim:

```js
$(function (){

  $('#button').on('click', function () {
    console.log('olá mundo');
  });
  $('#button').trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Clique em mim</button>
```

Porém já tem um bom tempo que eu não uso mais o jQuery.

Como é que posso disparar (trigger) um evento SEM USAR JQUERY?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gerar eventos nativos em JavaScript nativo pode ser uma dor de cabeça. Lembro de há uns tempos ter feito um [teste para gerar evento `wheel` no MooTools](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/1.6.0/Specs/Element/Element.Event.js#L459-L554) e a função para disparar esse evento ficou assim:

```js
 function dispatchFakeWheel(type, wheelDirection){

  var event;
  try {
   // Firefox
   event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
   event.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
   attachProperties(event, wheelDirection);
   window.dispatchEvent(event);
  } catch (e){}

  try {
   // Chrome, PhantomJS, Safari
   event = document.createEvent('WheelEvent');
   event.initMouseEvent(type, 0, 100, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, null, null, null);
   attachProperties(event, wheelDirection);
   window.dispatchEvent(event);
  } catch (e){}

  try {
   // IE9
   event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
   event.initEvent(type, true, false);
   attachProperties(event, wheelDirection);
   window.dispatchEvent(event);
  } catch (e){}

  try {
   // IE10+, Safari
   event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
   event.initEvent(type, true, true);
   attachProperties(event, wheelDirection);
   window.dispatchEvent(event);
  } catch (e){}

  try {
   // IE8
   event = document.createEventObject();
   document.documentElement.fireEvent(type, event);
  } catch (e){}
 }
```

Mas hoje em dia há uma [nova API, Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event), que tenta normalizar isto e ser igual em todos os browsers. O IE não suporta, mas os outros suportam.

Segundo essa API podem criar-se também custom-events, ou seja com o nome que queiramos. Exemplo:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

function handler(e){
console.log(e.type, e.isTrusted);
}
btn.addEventListener('click', handler);
btn.addEventListener('meu-super-evento', handler);

var evt = new Event("click", {
  "bubbles": true,
  "cancelable": false
});
btn.dispatchEvent(evt); // evento click simulado

var evt = new Event("meu-super-evento", {
  "bubbles": true,
  "cancelable": false
});
btn.dispatchEvent(evt); // evento meu-super-evento
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Clique em mim</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

Nativamente isso deverá ser feito através do método [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) de um objeto [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget). O parâmetro indicado neste método deverá ser um objeto do tipo [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event). Ou seja, primeiro precisamos criar a instância do evento que desejamos disparar; nesse caso, para exemplificar, utilizarei os eventos `click` e `mouseover`.

```
const click = new Event("click");
const mouseOver = new Event("mouseover");
```

Buscamos pelo elemento alvo no DOM:

```
const button = document.getElementById("button");
```

E disparamos os respectivos eventos:

```
button.dispatchEvent(click);
button.dispatchEvent(mouseOver);
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
const click = new Event("click");
const mouseOver = new Event("mouseover");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
 alert("Click");
});

button.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
 this.style.color = "red";
});

button.dispatchEvent(click);
button.dispatchEvent(mouseOver);
```

```html
<button id="button">Clique em mim</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Outra forma será utilizando o `dispatchEvent`, que implica criar previamente o objeto que representa o evento.

```js
const botao = document.getElementById("button");

botao.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('olá mundo');
});


let evento = new Event('click'); //criar o evento para o click

botao.dispatchEvent(evento); //lançar o evento criado
```

```html
<button id="button">Clique em mim</button>
```

O evento pode ser configurado a nível de algumas propriedades:

- "bubbles": (Opcional) Booleano que indica se o event tem efeito de bolha. O valor por defeito é falso.
- "cancelable": (Opcional) Booleano que indica se o evento é cancelável. O valor por defeito é falso.
- "composed": (Opcional) Booleano que indica se este evento vai ativar outros eventos fora de um *shadow root*. O valor por defeito é falso.

Poderíamos assim criar um objeto `MouseEvent` configurando as suas propriedades antes de ser lançado:

```js
const botao = document.getElementById("button");

botao.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('olá mundo');
});


let evento = new MouseEvent('click', { /*agora MouseEvent*/
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
});

botao.dispatchEvent(evento); //lançar o evento
```

```html
<button id="button">Clique em mim</button>
```

[Referência para criação manual de eventos no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

[Referência para o objeto `Event` no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)

Comment: A resposta parece boa, mas na descrição esta `composed` e no exemplo esta `view`, acho que isto meio confuso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Agradeço o comentário. Sim de fato deixei como estava o [exemplo no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), mas concordo que fica mais claro sem `view`

Answer (score 3):

Não seria apenas a utilização do [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)?

```js
function Hello() {
  console.log('olá mundo');
}

document.getElementById('button').click();
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="Hello()">Clique em mim</button>
```

Veja também [a compatibilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click#Browser_compatibility) antes de adotar uma solução definitiva.

[Nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2381572/4843158) possui várias outras opções de como fazer isso.

Comment: Sim é um atalho e funciona, sem precisar escrever tudo, o new Event é interessante para algumas configurações e/ou outros tipos de eventos e até eventos customizados. no caso atual `.click` resolve perfeitamente ;) +1

Answer (score 3):

Para dispara um evento `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`:

> Dispara um Event para o EventTarget especificado, invocando os
>   EventListeners especificados, em uma ordem apropriada. O processamento
>   normal das regras (including the capturing and optional bubbling
>   phase) aplica-se a eventos disparados manualmente com dispatchEvent().
>   [EventTarget.dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

Para capturar um evento `addEventListener()`:

> O **addEventListener()** registra uma única espera de evento em um único
>   alvo.  O alvo do evento pode ser um único elemento em um documento, o
>   documento em si, uma janela, ou um XMLHttpRequest.
>   [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)

```js
//Atribuo o elemento a variável btn
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

//Crio um evento novo chamado Clicado
var event = new Event('Clicado');

//Criar uma função para executar quando evento clicado for capturado
btn.addEventListener("Clicado", function(){
  console.log("o evento clicado foi disparado!!");
}, false);

//Dispara o evento
btn.dispatchEvent(event);

//IE e browsers em versões antigos utilizam o fireEvent
//btn.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Botão</button>
```